# One Observable, Multiple Subscribers, Different cases, Different share() behavior using rxjs5

Tags: javascript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

When two subscribers subscribe to an observable:

```
  let s = Observable.interval(1000).take(2).do(x => console.log('hey'));
  s.subscribe(n => console.log('subscriber  1 = ' + n));
  s.subscribe(n => console.log('subscriber  2 = ' + n));
```

The console logs the following:

> 'hey'
>    'subscriber  1 = 0'
>    'hey'
>    'subscriber  2 = 0'
>    'hey'
>    'subscriber  1 = 1'
>    'hey'
>    'subscriber  2 = 1'

Using `.share()`:

```
let s = Observable.interval(1000).take(2).do(x => console.log('hey')).share();
  s.subscribe(n => console.log('subscriber  1 = ' + n));
  s.subscribe(n => console.log('subscriber  2 = ' + n));
```

the console logs:

> 'hey'
>    'subscriber  1 = 0'
>    'subscriber  2 = 1'
>    'hey'
>    'subscriber  1 = 0'
>    'subscriber  2 = 1'

So, i managed to share the same data to more than 1 subscribers.
Executing the following test:

```
let s = Observable
    .from([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
    .filter(v => v > 0)
    .do(v => console.log('from', v));

  s.filter(v => v % 3 === 0)
    .subscribe(v => console.log('---0---', v));
  s.filter(v => v % 3 === 1)
    .subscribe(v => console.log('---1---', v));
  s.filter(v => v % 3 === 2)
    .subscribe(v => console.log('---2---', v));
```

logs:

> 'from', 1 'from', 2 'from', 3 '---0---',3 'from', 1 '---1---',1
>   'from', 2 'from', 3 'from', 1 'from', 2 '---2---', 2 'from', 3

Once again, i used `share()`:

```
 let s = Observable
    .from([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
    .filter(v => v > 0)
    .do(v => console.log('from', v))
    .share();

  s.filter(v => v % 3 === 0)
    .subscribe(v => console.log('---0---', v));
  s.filter(v => v % 3 === 1)
    .subscribe(v => console.log('---1---', v));
  s.filter(v => v % 3 === 2)
    .subscribe(v => console.log('---2---', v));
});
```

Even though i used `share()`, the from data were logged in exactly the same way as the previous attempt without `share()` (from 1 from 2 from 3 were logged 3 times each, 1 for each subscriber).

So, what's the difference between the observables in these examples?

How can i share the data in the second case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Rxjs 4 you should see `from 1 from 2 from 3` only once. However, you will only have one filter logging. `Rx.Observable.from(array)` is emitting its sequence synchronously. As such, when `s.filter(v => v % 3 === 0).subscribe(v => console.log('---0---', v));` is executed, your `s` observable is already completed. You can see that here : [[jsfiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/mLra2nL4/). Output is :

```
from 1
from 2
from 3
---0--- 3
```

In Rxjs 5, the `share` operator now restarts the source when it has ended AND a new subscriber subscribes.  At the second filter, `s` is restarted. So you go three times through the source sequence production process.

To convince you of that, turn your synchronous sequence into an asynchronous sequence : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rqqvt28/). You should now get, which is what you expected :

```
from 1
---1--- 1
from 2
---2--- 2
from 3
---0--- 3
```

Curiously enough, this is not documented in the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md). You can however find some information about what motivated the changes [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/453#issuecomment-145165630) and [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/453#issuecomment-152276434) (in short you get improved `repeat` and `retry` semantics).

That said, you can still have the Rxjs 4 `share` operator by using `publish().refCount()`. But as explained before, your second filter will see no data because the source will already have completed. See here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nbww2av/).